# Printing double precision numbers with specifying the number of digits in the exponent

Tags: format, fortran, precision

I would like to print out `0.3194D-114`. Is there any way to do that?

I tried to use

```
write(111,"(2I4, D30.20E3)") i, j, ez1(i,j,k)
```

But I got an error Error:

> Period required in format specifier

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i tried to use  write(111,"(2I4, D30.20E3)") i, j, ez1(i,j,k) . But i got an error Error: Period required in format specifier

Comment: Please, put that into the question! That is important information, don't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Fortran 2008 Standard (Cl. 10.3.2), the exponent width is not allowed for the `D` edit descriptor:

> 1 An edit descriptor is a data edit descriptor (data-edit-desc),
>   control edit descriptor (control-edit-desc), or character string edit
>   descriptor (char-string-edit-desc).
>
> ```
> R1007 data-edit-desc       is I w [ . m ]
>                            [...]
>                            or D w.d
> ```

Specifying the exponent is only allowed for the `E`, `EN`, `ES`, and `G` edit descriptors (same clause and paragraph):

> ```
>                            or E w.d [ E e ]
>                            or EN w.d [ E e ]
>                            or ES w.d [ E e ]
>                            or G w [.d [ E e ] ]
> ```

If you can live with an `E` denoting the exponent (instead of `D`), you could use

```
write(111,"(2I4, E30.20E3)") i, j, ez1(i,j,k)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If i use the E edit descriptor, do you think it causes the conversion of the double precision number to the single precision?

Comment: Well, you are converting anyway (to decimal, to ASCII)...If you want to preserve the precision, use a binary format. But if you specify enough digits, the error is quite small.

Comment: Actually the problem is not the accuracy, but getting smallest number with a double precision. I will produce an image using the output and i  need to get the smallest number to arrange a proper colorbar. Maybe, i should use Awk to replace E with D, after printing out the numbers. i will try, this might work.